How to count results after advanced filtering
enter image description here
When i selected the advanced filtering, this statistic has not changed and still shows the total number.
Filtered Records = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TableItems))
It updates automatically only when i click on a row in the table.
enter image description here
I know I can filter tables using Slicer so statistics update automatically, but I want to use advanced filtering now.

The visual filter will not affect the calculating. It will only affect the display scope.  If you want the filter to affect the calculating, you need to add a filter visual and use that visual to filter data. Then the output will change automatically.
If you don't want the slicer visual, you need to modify your DAX to update the calculation logic.

So there is no way to do it -> onlyRead of user clicks on the advanced filter and automatically updates the count right bar ?

What I think is visual filter is for report developers , not report readers. If user wants to change to filter report, they should select in the slicer visual

Okay, Thank you .
